# Event triggering before queue dies spring rabbitmq

Tags: spring, events, queue, rabbitmq, die

I have a requirement to trigger an event before queue dies due to inactivty of queue so that I can get all the messages in the queue.

Can you guys please let me how long long a queue is active if dont set AUTODELETE for rabbitmq queue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Somehow related to your question - [RabbitMQ Event Exchange plugin](https://github.com/simonmacmullen/rabbitmq-event-exchange).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't set `AUTODELETE` for the queue explicitly, it won't die at all. You may lose messages, if you don't specify for them `PERSISTENT` flag, when you restart RabbitMQ. However it isn't related to the restart of your application: if Broker works, messages don't lose.

So, I don't see reason to get deal with some `event` if your queue isn't `AUTODELETE`.

From other side (with `AUTODELETE`) you queue continue to live untile a `Listener` is active. So, you can achieve your requirement with `death` when you are going to `stop` the listener.